# nodejs and webserver communication

Tags: node.js, socket.io

This may seem like a stupid question but is it possible to establish a connection between a webserver and a nodejs application? I know that I can make requests from the nodejs server but is it possible to do something the other way around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the webserver in question allows you to make outgoing network connections, you just use whatever features it has for doing so to connect to your node.js server and make a request, whether an HTTP request or some generic TCP request. For example, if the webserver were running PHP, you'd probably use the `cURL` PHP module to make an HTTP connection, or `fsockopen()` along with `fread()` and `fwrite()` for a raw TCP connection.

Note that some hosting arrangements may disallow outgoing connections.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request#readme)-library to do a HTTP request to another node.js server.

Comment: Actually I want if possible to make a request from a webserver(not a node.js) to the node.js server

Comment: What software are you using as server-software?